# Rails Nested Resource (New)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a nested resource, where `todolist` is the parent and the `todoitem` is the child.

```
resources :todolists do
    resources :todoitems 
end
```

I have created an `Add Todo List` link where it invokes `new_todolist_todoitem` found in `routes.rb`.

```
new_todolist_todoitem GET    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/new(.:format)      todoitems#new
```

In my `todolists/show.html.erb` file, I have included this line of code:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Todo Item', new_todolist_todoitem_path(@todolist.id) %>
```

And in my `todoitems/_form.html.erb`, I have also included the nested parameters inside of it:

```
<%= form_for([@todolist, @todoitem]) do |f| %> --> Error is on this line
    <% if @todoitem.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@todoitem.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todoitem from being saved:</h2>
```

In my `todoitems_controller.rb`, I put these down for `new` and `create` methods:

```
  # GET /todoitems/new
  def new
    @todoitem = Todoitem.new
  end

  # POST /todoitems
  # POST /todoitems.json
  def create
    @todoitem = @todolist.todoitems.new(:todoitem_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todoitem.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todoitem, notice: 'Todoitem was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todoitem }
  else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todoitem.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error stating:

```
undefined method `todoitems_path' for #<#<Class:0x007feaa79e8da8>:0x007feaa5d0d878>
```

If anybody has a possible solution to fix this problem or suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. According to the stack trace, the Parameters Request is: `{"todolist_id"=>"2"}`

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting `@todolist` instance variable in your controller code but you are using it in the `form_for [@todolist, @todoitem]` tag. Make sure you have one set in your controller. Usually it is done in the `before_filter` like so:

```
class Todoitem
  before_filter :set_todolist

  def set_todolist
    @totolist = Todolist.find(params[:todolist_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: What if I have done that already? I just forgot to include it in this question. Is there anything else that I can do? I checked if there was a spelling error, but there wasn't any... @uzbekjon

Comment: Alright, let's see. You are getting `todoitems_path undefined` error. So, this means that your code is trying to access that path. Let's figure out where exactly that's happening. Could you please include full stack trace of your error?

Comment: Oh I'm at work right now, but I'll be happy to post it once I get back... haha @uzbekjon

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to note about this and hopefully it solves your issue.

In your `todolists/show.html.erb`, you can just pass the `@todolist` in your `link_to`

`<%= link_to 'Add Todo Item', new_todolist_todoitem_path(@todolist) %>`

Then some changes need to be made to your controller:

`todoitems_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_todolist

def create
  @todoitem = Todoitem.new(todoitem_params)

  # Assuming Todoitem belongs_to Todolist
  @todoitem.todolist_id = @todolist.id
  ...
end

private

def set_todolist
  @todolist = Todolist.find(params[:todolist_id]
end
```

Make sure your params are correct as well.